# NIO Files.write with OpenOption: write bytearray to unexist folder in one line

Tags: java, nio, file-writing

I'm trying to save byte array to a new folder and new file with NIO Files.write():

```
if (!Files.exists(folderName)) {
    Files.createDirectory(folderName);
}

Files.write(Paths.get(folderName.toString(), fileName), content,
    StandardOpenOption.WRITE, 
    StandardOpenOption.CREATE, 
    StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING);
```

Is there some OpenOption to create new folder if it doesn't exist? I want to write to file with one line code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that I can use next:

```
Files.write(Files.createDirectories(folderName).resolve(fileName), content);
```

Files.createDirectories checks if the directory already exists and will not throw an exception.